# Related Image Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am thinking of making a doctor Discord.js bot.
Is there a way for me to have an original image (an x-ray in this case) and making it so that if the user posts a similar image in the chat then the bot says a message.

If this is not possible, then sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow !
After searching for some time on the Internet, I found the [looks-same-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/looks-same-plus) npm module.

It compares both images' pixels and returns `true` if both images "look" the same.
This version (with the plus) allows you to compare images using their url, without needing them to be downloaded, which may come in super useful in your case.

I'd suggest you to browse through their [documentation](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same#comparing-images), I'm sure it will be easy for you to understand in no time !

I hope this was what you were looking for,
Have a nice day, and good luck !